# Update community ad requirements to allow retina goodness

Tags: feature-request, advertising, retina

Retina screens are becoming more and more of a thing. It's too late for this year's crop, but for next year, could the ad requirements be updated so that the required size is **440 x 500 pixels**. Some sites are [already doing this](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1884/12544), and it's working ok:

[image: NARWHALS NARWHALS SWIMMING IN THE OCEAN, CAUSING A COMMOTION BECAUSE THEY ARE SO AWESOME]

Comment: Retina seems to be a somewhat vague apple brand name. I take it you mean high definition screens?

Comment: @RichardTingle Retina is pretty universal terminology, but I'll let you have 'high pixel density' if you prefer.

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm pretty sure we all know what Retina means - just because SameSong can't use it because they would get sued doesn't mean it doesn't describe exactly what they do too.

Comment: It seems to be defined as "sufficient pixel density such that at the typical viewing range (variable) you cannot see the pixels.  It feels like it's mostly made of wiggle room for marketers

Comment: @RichardTingle That's how it's marketed to consumers. As a developer, retina means 'twice the pixels'.

Comment: @fredley That's how it's marketed to developers. As a consumer, retina means ‘twice the price’.

Comment: We are doing this on [Mathematica.SE](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/community-promotion-ads-2014) as well.